# bootstrap - input date type cause form-control overlap each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

**If I decrease the view area width, Input date type cause form-control overlap each other** 
 [**Test Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PS9YBywA9UYnSKBkBtf0?p=preview)

```
<div class="container">
  <h4>Date input type overlap issue</h4>
  <h4>Please reduce view width</h4>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Birth Date</span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

**It is expected to show this**

[image]

**Instead it shows this in chrome (overlapping date input)**

[image]

Comment: Try using bleeding-edge `master` branch of Bootstrap

Comment: @cvrebert. It's not working, Thanks.

Comment: Possibly you're encountering https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346051

Comment: yes it is the same issue. but the fix not working. i think it is a bug.

Comment: Well yeah, it's a bug in Chrome. Anyway, on extra-small screens, giving each of the inputs their own row is probably more user-friendly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Would your Viewport have enough width to accommodate both the input group in the same line ?

Try col-xs-12

Comment: I use col-xs-6, so it should accommodate 2 input in a row, it should not overlap. If I change date input type to number or text, it is work as expected.

Comment: May be the CSS properties of Date is overriding the bootstrap property. In console, try disabling the date input property.